# can we remove docker-compose down from steps?

Tags: docker-compose

Is it necessary to use "docker-compose down" before "docker-compose up". I dont want my application go down. I am using docker-compose at this point of time and having no plan to move to kubernetes etc.

If we remove "docker-compose down" then how it will handle the orphan-volumes and images?

Any pointer is highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Sanjiv

Comment: If my answer answered your question, it's customary to accept it :)

Answer (score 3):

No, you don't necessarily have to use `docker-compose down` before a `docker-compose up`. If you use `docker-compose up` on a running service stack, `docker-compose` will just **recreate the services that have been changed**. Changed either through:

- a changed `docker-compose.yml`, or
- updated images (either because you pulled new images, or rebuild them yourself).

To remove orphaned volumes, you have to issue a special flag `--remove-orphans` , see [docker-compose up](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/up/). But that behavior is the same with `docker-compose down`.

Also `images` are not changed with neither command. The difference is that with `docker-compose down` & `docker-compose up`, all running `containers` are removed and recreated from their `images`. So in case data was written inside the container, that data will be lost.

Comment: thanks hjsimpson. but sometimes it pull the images with sha256 though i have mentioned tag in docker-compose.yml file. next time docker-compose up failed with error no image found.

Comment: That is very difficult to answer, because it can have any number of reasons, the registry you are pulling from, your connection, ... If it works sometimes and sometimes not, the problem is likely not connected to docker itself.